# Run function when not on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've created a function that toggles the class `click` among siblings to show/hide them every 5 seconds

```
$(function() {
    var lis = $(".wwa-officers.class .news_item"),
        currentHighlight = 0;
        N = 5;//interval in seconds
    setInterval(function() {
        currentHighlight = (currentHighlight + 1) % lis.length;
        lis.removeClass('click').eq(currentHighlight).addClass('click');
    }, N * 1000);
});
```

But I want it to stop when the mouse is hovering the element to allow the users to read the info displayed in each element

I've tried the following, but doesn't seem to be working...

```
$(function(){
    $('.wwa-officers').on('mouseenter mouseleave', function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('class');
    });
});
```

Comment: The reason why your solution is not working is, that when your method is binded to a set of elements matching criteria, those item's may change criteria however the binded methods are still binded.

Comment: @xcy7e all right... And how can I modify that?

Comment: nAviD's answer should work. He changes for the criteria inside the function (if/hasClass) instead binding on .class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
  ...
 setInterval(function() {
      if(!$('.wwa-officers').hasClass('class')){
        currentHighlight = (currentHighlight + 1) % lis.length;
        lis.removeClass('click').eq(currentHighlight).addClass('click');
      }
    }, N * 1000);
...
```